# jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.postProcess(Lorg/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory;)V

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am facing a problem related to dependency I guess. Using Spring, JPA and Hibernate.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>News</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>News</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.data.version>1.7.0.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.M1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-leg-rc</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.l3s.boilerpipe</groupId>
        <artifactId>boilerpipe</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>            
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-urlshortener -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-urlshortener</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev45-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode/google-api-translate-java 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-translate-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.92</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.semispace/semispace-google-transport -->
    <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.semispace</groupId>
        <artifactId>semispace-google-transport</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.client/google-api-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx_utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency> 


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-mxj-db-files</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.25.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Classifier4J</groupId>
        <artifactId>Classifier4J</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ecs</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecs</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.xxx</id>
        <name>news files</name>
        <url>http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        <snapshots>                
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <finalName>news</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Now what Error I am getting is :

```
22-Jul-2016 00:36:49.778 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'otherSocialMediaUploader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.agrud.agp.news.repo.NewsSummarizedRepo com.agrud.agp.socialmedia.helper.OtherSocialMediaUploader.otherSummerizedNewsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newsSummarizedRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.postProcess(Lorg/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.agrud.agp.news.repo.NewsSummarizedRepo com.agrud.agp.socialmedia.helper.OtherSocialMediaUploader.otherSummerizedNewsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newsSummarizedRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.postProcess(Lorg/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newsSummarizedRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.postProcess(Lorg/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.postProcess(Lorg/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 75 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a version issue. Try changing your Spring version 4.3.1.RELEASE. That is version used with Spring Data JPA version 1.7.0.RELEASE.